# Creating a view with two tables, where second table doesn't have unique IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, pivot

I’m very new to SQL, would appreciate any input you can provide on the following.

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. I would like to create a view that joins the two.

Table A includes a list of unique user IDs under column user_ID, and Table B also has a column user_ID but this list doesn’t have unique user IDs as the other columns provide more information around these user IDs.

Please see images in first response for examples.

I've done some reading on the standard VIEW and JOIN queries, however I'm not sure how I'd go about creating a view from A and B where the values in 'Attribute 1' would become their own columns in the view.

Can anyone please help shed some light on this?

Comment: Table A: http://s23.postimg.org/d7lcej80b/post_663929_142092353132.png
Table B: http://s4.postimg.org/prvyql8dp/post_663929_142092358474.png

View: http://s9.postimg.org/co1a64q5r/post_663929_142092358996.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW VW_User AS 
SELECT A.User_ID, A.Name, A.Email, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Attribute1 = 'a' THEN B.Attribute2 ELSE '' END) AS 'a', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Attribute1 = 'b' THEN B.Attribute2 ELSE '' END) AS 'b', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.Attribute1 = 'c' THEN B.Attribute2 ELSE '' END) AS 'c'
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.User_ID = B.User_ID 
GROUP BY A.User_ID;
```